C program to delete sequence of lines in a file
I thought fgets would make my program faster than if I used fgetc but because of my poor understanding on how fgets actually work my final code has a lot of issues like leaving empty lines at the bottom of the file.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file, *f;
    char line[100], l[100]; // buffers to move and copy lines in the file
    int count = 1, // this counts the line we're in right now 
        StartDelete = 6, //here the first line of the sequence that we're gonna delete
        EndDelete = 10, // the line where deleting end
        size = 10; // how many lines in the file

    file = fopen("data.txt", "w+"); // Open the file in read-write mode
    f = fopen("data.txt", "r+"); // open another handle for the file to skip the lines we wanna delete 

    if (file == NULL || f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //take user's input 
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        printf("name %d: ", i+1);
        assert( fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin ) );
        fprintf( file, "%s%s", "name: ", line );
    }
    
    rewind(file); // going back to the start of the file 
    
    //
    while( count <= EndDelete ) {
        count++;
        fgets(l, sizeof(l), f);
    }
    count = 0;// reset the lines counter to zero this time because of the way fgets work
    // Read each line and overwrite the file with lines that are not marked for deletion
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) { //moving to the lines in the file
        count++;//the line conter grows as we move forward in lines
        if (count > StartDelete) {
            fseek(file, -strlen(line), SEEK_CUR);//going back to the beginning of the line again because of the mechanism of fgets 
            fwrite(l, sizeof(char), strlen(l), file);//overwriting 
            if(fgets(l, sizeof(l), f));//moving to the next line we wanna overwrite with
            else break;
        }
    }

    // Truncate the file to remove any remaining content beyond the new end of file
    fseek(file, ftell(file), SEEK_SET);
    ftruncate(fileno(file), ftell(file));

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

I tried deleting two and three from:
one
two
three
four

and I get eventually:
one
four

but with extra empty line at the end.

You can't read from and write to the same file at the same time. Instead read the source file, and write the data you need to a second temporary file. Then rename the temporary file as the original source file, thereby overwriting it. Then you only need one single loop really (if the buffer you read into is big enough to hold the longest line).

Like @Someprogrammerdude told, open a temp file. Here is an example for you -- somewhat close to your needs.

Opening the same file multiple times (with or without different access modes) is implementation-defined. In other words, don’t do that.
(However, it does not mean you can’t both read and write to the file at the same time.)
There are three good options here.
Option 1 • Load & Save file
This option has three steps:

Load the file entirely into memory.
Modify your data in memory.
Overwrite the original file with the new data.

For almost anything normal people plan to do, this option is sufficient. It is also super-über-monkey-space-force convenient because you now have full string-editing capabilities over the file content.
Variant 1 • Use tmpfile() for your memory

Open the source file.
Open a tmpfile.
Read the source, making changes as you write to tmpfile.
Overwrite the source file with the tmpfile data.

This is actually my favorite option. The temporary file is often just a memory object that does not actually exist on disk.
Option 2 • Make new file, Delete old file
This works much like the variant of Option 1, except how we deal with the actual on-disk files.

Open the source file.
Open a destination file.
Read the source, making changes as you write to the destination.
Delete the source.
Rename the destination to the original source file name.

This is an exceedingly common option, but my least favorite. It is, however, the only real option for very large files.
Variant 2 • Make new temporary then copy back over the source
That is, instead of trying to delete the old and rename the new, just reopen both files and simply copy the new back over the old. This is less efficient, but overcomes some problems with the delete and rename method.
Option 3 • Seek, Read & Write

Open file in read-write mode.
Read until you discover where you wish to begin deleting.
Get the file pointer position with ftell()
Read until you discover where you wish to continue copying.
while (!eof)
a. read N bytes
b. save get position
c. seek put position
d. write N bytes
e. seek get position
Truncate the file

This solution is suboptimal because of all the overhead bookkeeping and the need to use OS-specific facilities to truncate the file to the new size. (Um... here’s an SO post about that.)
Okay, I lied. This is my least favorite. Don’t do this.


I thought fgets would make my program faster than if I used fgetc but because of my poor understanding on how fgets actually work my final code has a lot of issues like leaving empty lines at the bottom of the file.

Your assumption is incorrect.  Using fgetc() (and building a finite state automaton) allows you to count line endings, start copying char by char and end copying as soon as you matched the end, character by character.  Fgets() will not go faster, as fgets() is buffer based, the same as it is fgetc() and your bottleneck is in the actual sequence of read() calls (that are the same for both) and not the internal processing (the simpler the better)
Apart of this, fgetc() requires you to specify a buffer, with a limited, bounded size, and this will limit your program to handle lines no longer than the processing buffer you are reading.  Why? just because if you get a line longer than the buffer size, your line will be cut at the buffer size (minus one to allow for the string terminator) and will appear to you as two lines, and not one (you will need to check for a '\n' at the last position of the buffer --not at the last position of the string, so you need to check that the string completely fits the buffer and the last character is not a newline--, or when there's no more data on the file, complicating severely the processing to be error free)
IMHO, you should do it a la K&R, by building a small line counter, searching for the \n characters and copying data or not based on the line counter.  You are creating a finite state automaton that will process the characters based on the input, and the previous state (I use for this the last character received, and the line counter, compared with the array of linenumbers appearing in the array, the index to this list is incremented as the lines with specified numbers are found, and this makes the complete state of the automaton)  You will see this result in quite compact code, in which less than one third of the code is dedicated to the problem algorithm.
Next is a program ranges.c that will accept the following options:

-l lineno will activate printing of lines at the specified lineno
-n will activate the printing of the line numbers in front of the lines as 00000:  line header.
a list of files that will be read by the program, or
no list of files, which will make the program to read stdin.
This program will alternate printing of lines from line specified in parameter to the line before the next -l option.  Lines are not sorted before starting and are verified in the order specified in command line, so if you specify, for example -l 5 -l 3 the program will start printing from line 5 and will read until the end of the file. If you want the program to sort the line numbers that can be done by using qsort(3) and sort the array of line numbers before starting the work. The nucleus of the algorithm is in the process() function, at the end of the file.

ranges.c
/* This code is open source under BSD copyright license by the answer
 * author.
 * feel free to copy/edit/distribute it. 
 */
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define F(_fmt) "%s:%d:%s:"_fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__

#define ERR(_cod, _fmt, ...) do {                \
        fprintf(stderr, F(_fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        if (_cod) {                              \
            exit(_cod);                          \
        }                                        \
    } while (0)

/* max number of ranges possible */
#define MAX_RANGES 100

int rangelines[MAX_RANGES];
int n_ranges = 0;
int show_linenumbers = 0;

/* prototype of processing function */
void process(int rng[], int n_rng, FILE *f);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "l:n")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n': /* show line numbers */
            show_linenumbers = 1;
            break;
        case 'l': /* line */
            if (n_ranges >= MAX_RANGES) {
                ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                    "n_ranges(%d) overflow\n", n_ranges);
            }
            rangelines[n_ranges++] = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 10);
            break;
        }
    } /* while */

    argc -= optind; /* shift all processed options out */
    argv += optind;

    if (argc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            FILE *f = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (!f) {
                ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                    "fopen: %s: %s\n",
                    argv[i],
                    strerror(errno));
            }
            process(rangelines, n_ranges, f);
            fclose(f);
        } /* for */
    } else {
        process(rangelines, n_ranges, stdin);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} /* main */

void process(int rng[], int n_rng, FILE *in)
{
    int line_no = 0,
        rng_pos = 0;
    int c,
        last = '\n';  /* assume we have a \n before
                       * first char */
    int show = 0; /* start not showing */
    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
        if (last == '\n') {
            line_no++;
        }
        if (rng_pos < n_rng && line_no >= rng[rng_pos]) {
            show = !show;
            rng_pos++;
        }
        if (show) {
            if (show_linenumbers && last == '\n')
                printf("%05d: ", line_no);
            fputc(c, stdout);
        }
        last = c;
    } /* while */
    puts(""); /* print last \n */
} /* process */

